# Make synchronized folder with TFS in linux

Tags: linux, bash, tfs, inotifywait

I am using `TFS every where` on CentOS and I want to run a service to listen on directory  modifying this directory represent TFS local folder and for every (add or modify) it mirroring to TFS

I tried to use `inotifywait` and listen to event `create,modify` but I confusion when adding directory, when adding a directory 'ssss'

output:

```
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ CREATE,ISDIR ssss
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE 1
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY 1
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE www
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY www
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE 112
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY 112
/tfs_loacl_folder/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE asd
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question at all.  I'm also not sure what it is that you're trying to accomplish.  It almost sounds like you're trying to automatically pend changes to TFS that your inotify listener detects?  If so, what's the rationale?  Are you using local or server workspaces?

Comment: yes I want to automatically checkin the changes 

and about workspaces I created it using
`tf workspace -new Beta1 -collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Comment: I guess my question is, if you switch to a local workspace `tf workspace -new ... -location:local` and let `tf` do the scanning for you, by running `tf status`, how far away are you from your design goals?

Comment: What do you mean about `-location:local`

Comment: not exist in manual page 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: TFS local workspaces: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx were introduced in TFS 2012 (the MSDN document is for an older version, before they were introduced.)

Comment: That is amazing !!!!
is there any way to checkin the changes 
`File name                                      Change Local path
---------------------------------------------- ------ -------------------------
$/TestProject/BuildProcessTemplates/Models/Acc
inter face.php                                 edit   /home/motaz/motaz_tfs_local/TestProject/BuildProcessTemplates/Models/Acc/inter face.php

1 change(s)`

Comment: it is working just `tf checkin  -recursive root_folder`

Comment: I summarized this in an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like you're trying to avoid having to explicitly checkout files when you change them.  Team Foundation Version Control has this functionality already.

Team Foundation Version Control operates in two modes:

1. Checkout / edit / checkin, where you need to explicitly checkout a file for edit before changing the contents.  The file is even marked read-only (`0444`) until you run `tf checkout <filename>`.
2. Edit / merge / commit, where you can edit a file at any time, and running `tf status` will examine your local filesystem for changes and mark each change as an `edit`.

The latter is called "local workspaces", and can be enabled by passing the `-location:local` flag to `tf` when creating the workspace.  For example:

```
tf workspace -new Workspace01 -location:local -collection:https://tfs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

After that, you can edit files without needing to pend the changes explicitly.

Comment: is there any way that already exist in `tf` to know that there is edit happening ?

Comment: No, it will examine the filesystem when you run `tf status`.